# SUM UNIQUE VALUES, with a Condition

Tags: excel-formula

I just started my new job and of course my first task is to update and fix alle the excel files. Also I am not at all an excel professional.

My problem is the following:

- I need the amount of a specific date stamp (e.g. "DSS4") for each unique tool.
- Each tool has a certain amount of cavities, and for each cavity I need 1 date stamp
- But i don't want to count tools multiple times (e.g. Tool:"1000" should be counted only once) That means I just want to count the tools and their cavities, but not each versions.

[image: http://imgur.com/a/BUA5N]

```
=WENN(D6:D17=F7;SUMMENPRODUKT(--(A6:A17<>"");1/ZÄHLENWENN(A6:A17;A6:A17&"")*C6:C17))

=IF(D6:D17=F7;SUMPRODUcT(--(A6:A17<>"");1/COUNTIF(A6:A17;A6:A17&"")*C6:C17))
```

I really hope this all makes sense. Thank you all in advance, and sorry if my english isn't perfect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(IF($D$6:$D$17=F7,$C$6:$C$17/COUNTIFS($A$6:$A$17,$A$6:$A$17,$D$6:$D$17,F7)))
```

I think the translation is:

```
=SUMMEN(WENN($D$6:$D$17=F7;$C$6:$C$17/ZÄHLENWENNS($A$6:$A$17;$A$6:$A$17;$D$6:$D$17;F7)))
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter.  If done correctly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

Comment: @Stauderbeste please mark as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.